# crash while using cvMinMaxLoc of opencv3.2 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

As title, I am trying to use opencv3.2 cvMinMacLoc() to get the position and size of result image in iOS, but get the error message like this :

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /Users/kyle/code/opensource/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 943
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/kyle/code/opensource/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:943: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat
```

By running this code :

```
- (void) test:(cv::Mat)image{
   NSLog(@"into test");
   UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo"];
   cv::Mat roiImg = [self cvMatFromUIImage: logo];
   cv::Mat displayImg = image.clone();
   cv::Mat result;
   result.create(image.rows-roiImg.rows+1, image.cols-roiImg.cols+1, CV_32FC1);

   cv::matchTemplate(image, roiImg, result, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
   double minValue, maxValue;
   CvPoint minLoc, maxLoc;
   cvMinMaxLoc(&result, &minValue, &maxValue, &minLoc, &maxLoc);//crash happends here!
}

#pragma mark - Protocol CvVideoCameraDelegate
#ifdef __cplusplus
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat &)image{
   // Do some OpenCV stuff with the image
   [self test:image];
}

#endif
```

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: Use the C++ function, not the obsolete C version: "cv::minMaxLoc"

Comment: hi @Miki, thanks for your help.
I use OpenCV3.2 framework from cocoapods(https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenCV). It seems cannot call cv::minMaxLoc(&src, &minVal, &manVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc) function.

Comment: Yes you can. Use cv::Point, and remove the reference (&) where not needed

Comment: @Miki Yes! You are right! Xcode does not show up cv::minMaxLoc automatically but it works! Thank you so much! You are my hero~ May I have your help to answer the question? I want to correct this, thank you again!